# My Linux book has many references to xinetd but I can't find it?

Tags: xinetd

Can't see it anywhere, is it called something different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just not installed by default. Install it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install xinetd
```

Comment: Does this mean that there are no more services that are launched via inetd/xinetd?

Answer (score 0):

Xinetd is a fairly fancy [service dispatcher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-server). It's available as a [package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xinetd). Most Ubuntu installations only need the features of the more basic [inetd](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xinetd) program (if at all), so that's what you get by default. If you need xinetd's advanced features, install it explicitly.